# iPod Shuffle 2nd gen won't turn on:

Tags: itunes, battery, charging, ipod, ipod-shuffle

I have a ten year old iPod Shuffle 2nd gen with original dock charger. After some years on shelf it won't turn on. It's charging when connected to adapter. It's also not recognised by iTunes (Windows 7 iTunes 12.4.3).

Charging: first it charges (continuous orange light,) then after some time, (I think when the battery's full,) it blinks orange 3-4 times then the light disappears.

Done everything that Apple Support tells me!

Comment: It's more like 15 years old. Pretty sure the battery is going to be EoL after that time.

Comment: @Tetsujin thanks for response , Does this explain not connecting to itunes?

Comment: I don't have much experience with the Shuffles. I do still have a Classic from even earlier, which I've just connected to test [last time I tried it it did still work] At the moment it's claiming 'very low battery, please wait'… One thing that was always important for the Classics, & idk if the Shuffles have even the same switch let alone the same issue, is that you **must** switch the Lock off [red/white slider at the top] before connecting, or it will not work.

Comment: An hour or so later, I did persuade the classic to sync, though I do think its HD is dying, as it keeps erroring if I try to sync the whole 30GB it's supposed to be able to take. [I doubt that really helps you, but just for sake of completeness] One further thing I did discover was that Coconut Battery can't see the iPod [which might have provided more useful info]